# nav bar .active not working

Tags: html, css

Hello for some reason I can't get the `:active a {` attribute to work for my navigation bar. I tried looking up fixes but nothing seems to work.

**My HTML:**

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id='active'><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="request_fix.html">REQUEST FIX</a></li>
            <li><a href="find_us.html">FIND US</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav li:active a {
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing ID, class, and state here. Try this:

```css
#nav li.active a {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #808080;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="request_fix.html">REQUEST FIX</a></li>
            <li><a href="find_us.html">FIND US</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting class `.active` but your selector uses pseudo-class `:active`.

Try this:

```
#nav li.active a {
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #808080;
}
```

Learn more about `:active` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active